# Linux shell single quotes and double quotes in one command

Tags: linux, shell

I need your help to make this command work:

```
ssh -t user@localhost "cd /tmp ; PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;log\007"' ; bash"
```

Here is the error that I get:

```
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
Connection to localhost closed.
log007' ; bash: command not found
```

Thanks

Comment: Just escape double quotes with backslash (`\"`).

Comment: @Slava, thanks it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to escape double quotes with backslash (`\"`):

```
ssh -t user@localhost "cd /tmp ; PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne \"\033]0;log\007\"' ; bash"
```

Answer (score 1):

It goes through two shells, meaning two string expansions, so escape the inner parts:

```
ssh -t user@localhost "cd /tmp ; PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne \"\033]0;log\007\"' ; bash"
```